# What's different between Python and Javascript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

Are Python and JavaScript regular expression syntax identical?

If not, then:

1. What are the important differences between them
2. Is there a python library that "implements" JavaScript regexps?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a comparison table here:

[Regex Flavor Comparison](http://web.archive.org/web/20130830063653/http://www.regular-expressions.info:80/refflavors.html)

Comment: Thanks! My attempts at googling the answer failed.

Now, I guess the follow up question is: "Is there a python library that 'implements' javascript regexps?"

Comment: I don't know of one. What is the root reason for wanting one?

Comment: I'd like a Python library compatible with EMCA regex because I want consistency between a regex search in Python on the back-end and a Javascript one on the front-end.

Comment: The link point to TOC now.
Wikipedia has some resources on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: The link isn't useful anymore. It would have been better to answer the question directly.

Answer (score 7):

**Part 1**
They are different; One difference is Python supports Unicode and Javascript doesn't.

**Part 2**
Read [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/).  It gives information on how to identify the back-end engines (DFA vs NFA vs Hybrid) that a regex flavour uses.  It gives tons of information on the different regex flavours out there.

There is *way* too much information to convey on a single SO answer, so you're better off having a solid piece of reference material on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html vs http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html