# Extract associated values from text using NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to extract Cardinal(CD) values associated with Units of Measurement and store it in a dictionary. For example if the text contains tokens like "20 kgs", it should extract it and keep it in a dictionary.

Example:

1. for input text, *“10-inch fry pan offers superb heat conductivity and distribution”*, the output dictionary should look like, `{"dimension":"10-inch"}`
2. for input text, *"This bucket holds 5 litres of water."*, the output should look like, `{"volume": "5 litres"}`

   ```
   line = 'This bucket holds 5 litres of water.'
   tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
   tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
   ```

The above line would give the output:

```
[('This', 'DT'), ('bucket', 'NN'), ('holds', 'VBZ'), ('5', 'CD'), ('litres', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ('water', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

Is there a way to extract the CD and UOM values from the text?

Comment: did you try to use `stanford nlp` ?

Comment: Any POS tagger should label the CDs pretty accurately, and a fixed mapping from units to your label set would probably capture most instances. I tend to shy away from hand-building fixed lexicons, but this seems like an application where you can get pretty good coverage with a simple list. E.g., given your examples 'lit(er|re)(s?)' -> 'volume', 'inch(es)?' -> 'dimension' (or, 'length' perhaps). You'll have to handle some more complex cases, like 'square meters' or 'in^3', and there will be a few ambiguous references (e.g. 'knots' is both a length and a speed). But those should be rare.

Comment: @Kasra:Anything specific that I should refer in **stanford nlp** for the solution?

Comment: @Dork as far as i know `stanford nlp` is used for special tagging such as extract special names or ... , i'm not sure it could help you but i suggest to have search related to your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how flexible you need the process to be. You can play around with nltk.RegexParser and come up with some good patters:

```
import nltk

sentence = 'This bucket holds 5 litres of water.'

parser = nltk.RegexpParser(
    """
    INDICATOR: {<CD><NNS>}
    """)

print parser.parse(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)))
```

Output:

```
(S
  This/DT
  bucket/NN
  holds/VBZ
  (INDICATOR 5/CD litres/NNS)
  of/IN
  water/NN
  ./.)
```

You can also create a corpus and train a chunker.

Comment: :Is there a built-in method to separate the text from the tags after POS-tagging?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, not sure if it helps - but I wrote it in Javascript.
Here:
http://github.com/redaktor/nlp_compromise

It might be a bit undocumented yet but the guys are porting it to a 2.0 branch now.

It should be easy to port to python considering
[What's different between Python and Javascript regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636485/whats-different-between-python-and-javascript-regular-expressions)

And : Did you check pythons NLTK? : http://www.nltk.org

Comment: The Javascript library is good, I will try experimenting more of it. 
About the nltk book, the sample code I tried was part of the book.