# Javascript regexp replace capturing

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to use regex in a Nodejs app. I usually use it in  Python and it seems to have [some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636485/whats-different-between-python-and-javascript-regular-expressions).

Here is the problem : 
I have this string `\newcommand{\hello}{@replace}` and I want to replace `@replace` by `REPLACED` in the second curly bracelets ONLY when I found `\hello` in the first curly bracelets. So the expected result is : `\newcommand{\hello}{REPLACED}`

I try this:

```
r = new RegExp('\\newcommand{\\hello}{(.*?)}');
s = '\\newcommand{\\hello}{@replace}';
s.replace(r, 'REPLACED');
```

But nothing is replaced... any clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = new RegExp(/\\newcommand{\\hello}{@replace}/);
s = '\\newcommand{\\hello}{@replace}';
let a = s.replace(r, '\\newcommand{\\hello}{REPLACED}');

console.log(a)
```

Output would be : `"\newcommand{\hello}{REPLACED}"`

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid... I trust the Firefox console return when I press enter. Witch return me `"\\newcommand{\\hello}{@replace}"` but when print it with `console.log` it's works ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly. Is this what you're looking for?

```
function replaceWith(myReplacement) {
    var original = "\\newcommand{\\hello}{@replace}";
    var regex = "{\\hello}{@replace}";

    return original.replace(regex, `{\\hello}{${myReplacement}}`)
};


console.log(replaceWith("World"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex at all to perform this kind of operation. You can simply use string at first parameter:

```
s = '\\newcommand{\\hello}{@replace}';
s.replace('@replace', 'REPLACED'); // => "\newcommand{\hello}{REPLACED}"
```

Comment: You right! I focused on RegExp but your solution also works.